# Remove page title in Wordpress custom page template

Tags: wordpress, page-title

I'm trying to create a custom page template by copying page.php, changing its name to smth different and playing around with it.

I would like to remove the title in my custom page template - (not on a specific page, but in the whole template!).

Reading here and there I see that the solution seems to be removing this:

```
<h2>” title=”<?php the_title(); ?>”><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
```

Unfortunately, I don't see that line in my custom template, this is how the code looks:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Links
*/


get_header(); ?>


<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>



<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

What should I remove here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are *almost* there, just find the PHP file, which starts with `content-`, edit it, and remove the `the_title()` function.

Why? Well, because this line of code `get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );` seeks for a PHP file in your theme's folder, which starts with `content-`.

**EDIT**: The function will do a PHP `require()` for the first file that exists among these, in this priority:

- `wp-content/themes/your_theme/loop-index.php`
- `wp-content/themes/your_themechild/loop-index.php`
- `wp-content/themes/your_theme/loop.php`
- `wp-content/themes/your_themechild/loop.php`

So check those files too.

Comment: Ok, so it works - partially :) I found content-page.php and removed the function, but the usual page templates "suck" from that file as well, so now there are no titles in all of my pages ;) Maybe I should copy the content-page.php, rename it to let's say content-custom.php and put it like that:     get_template_part( 'content', 'custom' ); ? Does this have a chance to work or should I put it differently?

Comment: YES, do that exactly, copy the `content-page.php`, rename it to let's say `content-custom.php` and then `get_template_part( 'content', 'custom' ); `:)

Comment: Ok, in the end I did it the way I mentioned in my previous comment - it worked! My custom page template now has no title, but the default page template appears with title, which is how I wanted it to be. Now just wondering if it won't cause some future problems, any idea?

Comment: No, it will not cause any problems (well, define what do you mean by `problems`?)

Comment: Oh, any weird behaviour that a newbie can't predict :) but I'll stick to your opinion and keep it that way, thnx! :)